# how can I get the APP ID of a page that I own?

Tags: facebook

Is there anyway that I can get the App ID of a page that i own? The reason for this is to get a count on our web site count and userID of the user who has liked our page?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go to https://developers.facebook.com/apps 
[image]